# Conversion of TIFF file in a colorful pattern

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I have a TIFF file which I got after taking the standard deviation from 10 TIFF files. Now when I plot my TIFF file of standard deviation they give me color like this (attached below). But I want to get different color in my spatial data. Is it possible to get other scheme of color instead of this?

I am doing all this analysis in R

The example of my code is here

```
    library(raster)
    file <- list.files(path="", pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)
    s<- raster::stack(file)
    final <- calc(s, fun = sd)
    plot(final)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the GIS StackExchange! Could you be more specific? What environment are you using to display the raster? (from the image I would guess R?)

Comment: Yes I am using R -Sytze

Comment: Alright! And what package are you using for manipulating and displaying the raster? It is always helpful to include a code example, so people can directly see what you are doing. Could you include this?

Comment: Edited and updated the post -Sytze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to change the color scheme of your raster. One way would be to use the package `colorRamps` (see documentation) to create a color ramp and use it when plotting your raster data. The following is an example, using your code:

```
library(raster)
library(colorRamps)

file <- list.files(path = "", pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)
s <- raster::stack(file)
final <- calc(s, fun = sd)

breaks <- seq(0, 0.7, by = 0.1)
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))(length(breaks))

plot(file, col = palette)
```

The `colorRampPalette` returns a function to create a colour ramp from red to green. This function is called (on the same line) with the number of breaks you have specified, using a sequence starting with the smallest value in your raster to the highest value in your raster and with steps of 0.1. You could also directly assign colours to your plot, as follows:

```
...
plot(file, col = c("#FF0000","#DA2400","#B64800"))
```

Comment: Its very useful but one problem is that they give me error like this at the last line.  Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Hm, I expect that has to do with your raster. Did you make any additional changes to your code?

Comment: I didn't change it -Sytze

Answer (score 1):

There are many R packages for visualising data, especially spatial data and raster data. Your code uses the `plot()` function which is generally referred to as "base R" as it comes built-in when you install R. It is ok for simple plotting, but it's limitations soon become obvious when you try and make more complicated figures.

For plotting spatial data, I would recommend reading [Chapter 8 - Making maps with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html) in the *Geocomputation with R* book. It describes the common plotting packages and gives you examples of how to use them.

For example, the `tmap` package is pretty useful for plotting spatial data and raster data. You provide it with your data using `tm_shape()`, and then tell it what sort of data it is and how you want it plotted using `tm_*()` - in this case `tm_raster()` for raster data. You can specify the colour scheme using `palette =` ,  and a colour palette of your choice - see [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/) for a detailed explanation and examples of available colour palettes.

I use the `nz_elev` data from the `spDataLarge` package as an example.

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode('view')
library(spDataLarge)

nz_elev

# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1450, 1115, 1616750  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
# extent     : 995456.5, 2110457, 4741961, 6191961  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : elevation 
# values     : 0, 4140.333  (min, max)
```

Default `tmap` palette (`YlOrRd`):

```
tm_shape(nz_elev)+
  tm_raster()
```

[image]

Or providing it with a custom choice.

```
tm_shape(nz_elev)+
  tm_raster(palette = 'viridis')
```

[image]

Or another custom palette, this time ordered normally and reversed (prefix `-`).

```
tm_shape(nz_elev)+
  tm_raster(palette = 'RdPu')

tm_shape(nz_elev)+
  tm_raster(palette = '-RdPu')
```

[image][image]

By default `tmap` "categorises" colours by value, but you can override this to make a "continuous" colour scale. It's a little hard to tell the difference on the whole map of NZ, but the legend shows the difference.

```
tm_shape(nz_elev)+
  tm_raster(palette = '-RdPu', style = 'cont')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, detailed answer!